# Excel: different number of digits in the same column Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I have these numbers pasted as text in one sheet:

```
0.000180
0.000590
0.000850
0.000240
0.000290
0.000160
0.00419
0.000180
0.00187
0.000160
0.000310
0.000120
```

I would like to convert them to numbers in Excel. However, when do so, I lose the 0 at the end (e.g. 0.000180 become 0.00018). If I try to increase the number of decimals, then 0.00419 becomes 0.004190 which is not good(since I have to print these values for a report with the exact number of decimals). To make things even worse, I need to apply some conditional formatting (which is not working when numbers are pasted as text). Is there any possibility to have these values formatted as numbers and in the same time, to have values with different number of digits in the same column? thanks

Comment: Convert to numbers and then override the number format for those cells with fewer decimals places.

Comment: I am looking for an automatic solve since I have hundreds of columns and rows but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code it like this:

```
Sub Keep0s()

Dim c As Range
Dim MyStr As String
Dim x As Long
For Each c In Selection
    MyStr = "0.0"
    For x = 1 To Len(c) - 3
        MyStr = MyStr & "0"
    Next x
    c.NumberFormat = MyStr
    c = CDec(c)
Next c
End Sub
```

Insert the code into a module by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or [similar](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-enable-the-developer-tab-and-open-the-visual-basic-editor-in-word-and-excel-2016-and-office/).
Highlight the numbers stored as text that you want to convert, and then run the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot:)

Comment: one question about the code: I noticed that if the cell are blanks, a 0 is inserted; is it possible to avoid this? thanks!

Comment: I cannot edit the answer, I guess because it has been accepted. You need to insert this line: "If c = vbNullString Then GoTo MyNxtc" immediately after The "For each c" line, then type MyNxtC: immediately before "next c"

Answer (score 1):

## Case 1: you find a math rule

If you find some kind of rule for computing the number of significant digits that you want displayed from the number itself, then it's relatively easy: you create as many conditional formatting conditions as how many different number of digits you want, and for each condition you define a numeric format with that many digits.

For example, from your data I can guess that you want to display 3 significant digits. I don't know if that is true, but if this was the case you could create several conditions like:

- condition is formula: `=TRUNC(-LOG10(A1))+3=6` → format to 6 decimal places
- condition is formula: `=TRUNC(-LOG10(A1))+3=5` → format to 5 decimal places

plus as many of them as needed. Note that I am assuming you have converted text to numbers and that those numbers start from cell A1.

## Case 2: no math rule

If on the other hand there is no math rule, and you just have to keep the same number of characters as in the input text, you can do something similar to case 1.

Leave the text column as it is (say, starting from cell A1), and create one more column with the same data converted to numbers (say, from cell B1)

Then apply conditional formatting to column B, using a series of rules like

- condition is formula: `=LEN(A1)-2=6 → format` to 6 decimal places
- condition is formula: `=LEN(A1)-2=5 → format` to 5 decimal places

plus as many of them as needed.